# Dynamic references to figures in a R comment within Sweave document

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex, sweave

I would like to find a way to use the LaTeX `\ref{}` markup to comment in the R code within a Sweave .Rnw file.  Here are two examples, one in print

http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/ms/departments/sia/project/nlme/UGuide.pdf

and one to use to work with:

The .Rnw file

```
% File: example.Rnw

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{Sweave} 
\usepackage[margin = 10pt, font=small, labelfont={bf}]{caption}

\begin{document}

Here is an example file to show what I want to do.  I would like to figure out how to use the \LaTeX\ reference command to reference a figure being generated by R code.  Note in the R code, in a comment there is a reference to the figure, but of course the output file shows a verbatim copy of the \LaTeX\ markup.  Does anyone know how to get something for Figure \ref{fig2}?

<< example plot >>=
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

n <- 100
lambda <- 1 / 3 
x <- seq(0, qexp(0.999, rate = lambda), length = n)
q1.a <- data.frame(x =   x,
                   f =   dexp(x, rate = lambda),
                   F =   pexp(x, rate = lambda))

q1.a <- melt(q1.a, id.vars = 'x')
g <- ggplot(q1.a) +                                     # Produces \ref{fig1} 
       aes(x = x, y = value) + 
       geom_line() + 
       facet_wrap( ~ variable, scale = "free_y")
ggsave(g, filename = "example1.jpeg")                    
@

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{./example1}
\caption{Exponential Distribution based plots.}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

Here is more of what I would like to see:

<< example plot 2 >>=
ggsave(g + geom_point(), filename = "example2.jpeg")    # Produces Figure 2
@

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{./example2}
\caption{Exponential Distribution based plots with points and lines.}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and the pdf is build with the R commands

```
Sweave(file = 'example.Rnw',
       engine = "R",
       keep.source = 'TRUE',
       echo = 'TRUE',
       results = 'verbatim')

tools::texi2dvi(file  = "example.tex",
                pdf   = TRUE,
                clean = TRUE)
```

Any insight on how do this would be great.

Comment: You could use `brew` to process the `Rnw` file before `Sweave`.

Comment: Sweave input/code listing is a variant on the verbatim environment specifically to not try and interpret the `R` code as LaTeX. You are wanting `R` code comments to be interpreted as LaTeX. I don't know how, but maybe this re-phrasing will help with a solution.

Comment: @BrianDiggs Nice point. Your comment lead me to the solution I posted. Just requires a different `verbatim` environment that lets `LaTeX` parse some token.

Comment: @Ramnath, perfect solution, exactly what I was looking for.  I'll keep an eye out for any potential issues.

Comment: @Peter. You might want to refer to the `alltt` manual to understand what type of latex tokens get parsed. As long as your source code does not include those tokens, you will be fine, is what I think.

Comment: If you are looking for same solution when using `knitr` look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14058832/1104685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve this issue by redefining the `Sinput` environment in which source code is wrapped by `Sweave`. By default, it is a simple `verbatim` environment which is not processed by `latex` for tokens. The trick is to redefine it to use the `alltt` environment which allows some tokens to be parsed inside the `alltt` environment. Note that this might lead to unwanted side effects that I am not aware of, so use with caution!

Here is a reproducible example that works. If you compile it, you will generate a file where  `ref{fig1}` is replaced by the figure number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{alltt}
\renewenvironment{Sinput}{\begin{alltt}}{\end{alltt}}

\begin{document}

In this document, we will create a plot using `R`, and reference its position in 
the source code.

<<produce-plot, results = hide>>=
pdf('example1.pdf')
plot(1:10, 1:10)     # Produces Figure \ref{fig1}
dev.off()
@

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example1.pdf}
\caption{Figure 1}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```