# Dynamic LaTeX references in R comment with knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I had ask a similar question to this with respect to `Sweave` (
[Dynamic references to figures in a R comment within Sweave document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023256/dynamic-references-to-figures-in-a-r-comment-within-sweave-document)
) and would like to see if anyone as a similar answer when using `knitr`.

The goal is to have the following code chunk

```
<<"example", fig.cap = "some figure", highlight = FALSE>>=
# the following code generated Figure \ref{fig:example}
plot(1:10, 1:10)
@
```

have be displayed in the resulting .pdf as

```
# the following code generated Figure 1.1
plot(1:10, 1:10)
```

So far I have found that by setting `highlight = FALSE` the R code is placed into a `verbatim` environment in the resulting .tex file.  If the environment could be `alltt` instead of `verbatim` then we'd have the desired output.  Is it possible to have the non-highlighted code chunks be placed in `alltt` environments via a `knitr` option?

Comment: Based on these comments (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knitr/tgS5iCUpyhA), perhaps removing the highlight package and adding \usepackages{alltt} will use the corresponding environment for highlighting. Referencing may then be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added an example [072-latex-reference.Rnw](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/072-latex-reference.Rnw) in the `knitr-examples` repository. The basic idea is to restore the escaped `\ref{}` (which should have been `\textbackslash{}ref\{\}` in the default output).

Comment: Changing the regex to `gsub('\\\\textbackslash\\{\\}(\\w?)ref\\\\\\{(.+)\\\\\\}', '\\\\\\1ref{\\2}', txt)` extends compatibility to `c/.../vref` style references (hopefully without nasty side effects).

Comment: And - the `(.+)` should be non-greedy `(.+?)`, otherwise it only works for a single reference per chunk. `txt = gsub('\\\\textbackslash\\{\\}(\\w?)ref\\\\\\{(.+?)\\\\\\}', '\\\\\\1ref{\\2}', txt)` (I think.)