# Dynamic references to figures in Sweave

Tags: r, reference, latex, sweave

Before you say use search, I did, I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023256/dynamic-references-to-figures-in-a-r-comment-within-sweave-document), I tried it and it does not help, I assume it might be because of including it from another file. (not sure..)

I have a Sweave document I am writing using R studio. Running R code works perfectly, including other files works as well. Here are some examples of what the main file looks like:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\input{tex/introduction}
\input{tex/methods}
\SweaveInput{tex/analysis}
\input{tex/conclusions}
\SweaveInput{tex/further}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{tex/literature}

\appendix
\input{tex/appendix}

\end{document}
```

Then in one of the `.Rnw` files referenced by `\SweaveInput{}` I use something like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \label{fig1}
 \caption{This is a caption!}
 \centering
<<fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
...data and plotting...
@
\end{figure}

In figure \ref{fig1} we can see that there is...
```

and instead of a figure number I just get `[??]`

Do you maybe know why this is happening? and how can I fix it?

I looked at the `knitr` package as well but I don't know how to include an external file like in my example and I get other funny errors. Also, I don't know if it will work there. Basically I would have to do more research why my code doesn't work and I would just like to get the current code running.

Tnx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`label` needs to come after `caption`.  See for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23385

Comment: tnx.. that solved it! I wonder why I was able to use it the other way around in other basic `.tex` documents. :/

Comment: It works when in the wrong order, but refers wrongly to the previous number.  In this case there was no previous number.